# Эквивалент (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1) в Mongoose?

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Собственно вопрос в названии, как в Mongoose найти все данные, которые связаны с пользователем, id которого = 1?
В официальной документации нашёл только метод findOne() с последующим перечислением нужных полей, а вот как взять все и сразу, не нашёл...

Comment: `User.findOne({id: id}).exec().then(user=>console.log(user));`

Comment: @vp_arth уважаемый господин, добавьте свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его как правильный. Большое спасибо. Работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно видеть из [документации](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/), список полей опционален.

Просто не описывайте список полей вообще:

```
User.findOne({id: 1}).exec() // Получаем Promise
  .then(user=>console.log(user));
```